# vb.net, full number presentation with small double number

Tags: vb.net, double, numbers, presentation

if I have a small double in vb.net like this:

```
dim x as double = 0.00000003
```

a conversion to a string would produce a E-presentation (`3E-7`). in debugging the value it will be shown as full number (`0.00000003`).

how can I get the full number in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `.ToString()` method and a format string:

```
Dim y As String = x.ToString("F7")
```

[Standard Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
[Custom Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Note that this still requires you to choose a specific format.  If you want it to automatically match the string literal you used in your code, then you have a problem because that information is not preserved.